# A proof involving conditional distributions, Poisson, binomial

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a non-negative integer valued random variable. Let $Y$ be the number of successes in $X$ binomial trials. Prove that, if the distribution of $Y$ and $X\mid (Y=X)$ are identical, then $X$ must be Poisson distributed.

Comment: All this independently from the distr. of $X$?

Comment: Y is dependent on X of course. By the distribution of Y, the marginal distribution of Y is implied.